# PHP, MYSQL record not inserting

Tags: php, mysql

I have these two mysql tables:

```
--
-- Table structure for table `body`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `body`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `body` (
`bChar` bigint(10) NOT NULL,
`bPart` bigint(10) NOT NULL,
`bStr` int(3) NOT NULL,
`bDur` int(3) NOT NULL,
`bItem` bigint(10) NOT NULL,
`bHealth` int(3) NOT NULL,
`bSpd` int(3) NOT NULL,
`bMaxDur` int(3) NOT NULL,
`bCurse` int(1) NOT NULL,
`bAct` int(1) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Table structure for table `partybody`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `partybody`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `partybody` (
`pabChar` bigint(10) NOT NULL,
`pabPart` bigint(10) NOT NULL,
`pabStr` int(3) NOT NULL,
`pabDur` int(3) NOT NULL,
`pabItem` int(10) NOT NULL,
`pabHealth` int(3) NOT NULL,
`pabAct` int(1) NOT NULL,
`pabNum` int(4) NOT NULL,
`pabSlot` int(1) NOT NULL,
`pabSpd` int(3) NOT NULL,
`pabMaxDur` int(3) NOT NULL,
`pabCurse` int(1) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Here is the data in body:

```
(0, 25, 0, 0, 0, 120, 0, 0, 0, 1)
```

I have this php code:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM body WHERE bChar = ".$_SESSION['chNum'];
$result2 = mysql_query($query, $_SESSION['connect']) or die("Error 3:".mysql_error());
while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2)) {
   query = "INSERT INTO partybody VALUES(".$_SESSION['chNum'].",".$row2['bPart'].",".$row2['bStr'].",".$row2['bDur'].",".$row2['bItem'].",".$row2['bHealth'].",1,1,1,".$row2['bSpd'].",".$row2['bMaxDur'].",".$row2['bCurse'].")";
  mysql_query($query, $_SESSION['connect']) or die("Error 4a:".mysql_error());
}
```

I just added `$row2['bCurse']` to the `INSERT` and I changed my error message from Error 4: to Error 4a: but when I execute the program I get this:

```
Error 4:Column count doesn't match value count at row 1.
```

I tried clearing my cache but that didn't help. Ideas?

Comment: echo your query and run in database to see whether any problem in your query.

Comment: We assume you actually have `$query` and not `query`, which would be a syntax error.  If you changed them and still get the old error, perhaps you forgot to upload the new file?

Comment: Your "party body" table above has 10 columns and you're trying to insert close to 12 values into it through your query (above). How would it work?

Comment: @verisimilitude it's got 12 columns...

Comment: @verisimilitude Look at the code more closely. He is not simply moving data from one table to another but also adding some additional data before inserting new records in the second table. Therefore his queries are perfectly legit.

Comment: I'm guessing somewhere in that sql-injection-risk rife query of yours some of the values are not coming out, so there are empty values and therefore values like `0,,,,1`. I would suggest printing out the query you're generating before executing it, or as part of the error, so you can see what is *actually* being sent to SQL, instead of what you think is. Oh, and if possible stop using mysql_* - use the mysqli prepared statements if you can.

Comment: Do you have any quotes/commas in any of the data? As suggested, echo the query statement out to make sure.  Also, as you "changed my error message from Error 4: to Error 4a:" but the old error message appears - you didn't forget to save / upload the file to your server? Or upload to the wrong place?

Comment: @All: Agree. the above queries are legit. I tried the above code at my end and it works like a charm. I'm sure that the case maybe what Cylindric has mentioned, empty values getting in $query which is going out to SQL.

Comment: I'm running locally using WAMP so there is no upload problem. I tried var_dump($query) right after the INSERT is prepared and commented out the mysql_query and still get the same error message with no var_dump

Comment: I finally got a var_dump on the query to work and this is what I get: 'INSERT INTO partybody VALUES(2,25,500,104,60,100,1,1,1,0,104,1)  Looks fine to me

Comment: Problem solved, another script was screwing things up after the fact and it just happened to have the same error code

Comment: Glad to know that you found a way out of your predicament :)

Answer (score 0):

If the database is still populated only with test data you could output all of the query strings and check visually if something might stink. Look for query parts that might look like this `number,,number`.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM body WHERE bChar = ".$_SESSION['chNum'];
var_dump($query);
$result2 = mysql_query($query, $_SESSION['connect']) or die("Error 3:".mysql_error());
while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2)) {
   query = "INSERT INTO partybody VALUES(".$_SESSION['chNum'].",".$row2['bPart'].",".$row2['bStr'].",".$row2['bDur'].",".$row2['bItem'].",".$row2['bHealth'].",1,1,1,".$row2['bSpd'].",".$row2['bMaxDur'].",".$row2['bCurse'].")";
   var_dump($query)
   //mysql_query($query, $_SESSION['connect']) or die("Error 4a:".mysql_error());
}
```

BTW is the missing dollar sign in front of `query` a typo in the following line?

```
query = "INSERT INTO partybody VALUES(".$_SESSION['chNum'].",".$row2['bPart'].",".$row2['bStr'].",".$row2['bDur'].",".$row2['bItem'].",".$row2['bHealth'].",1,1,1,".$row2['bSpd'].",".$row2['bMaxDur'].",".$row2['bCurse'].")";
```

Comment: The missing $ is a typo, it's correct in the code. I tried var_dump($query) after my INSERT and it didn't dump anything out. The strange thing is why is the error message still saying "Error 4:" even though I commented that piece of code out?

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that you are executing the correct script/code?

Comment: As sure as I can be, is ther some way I can tell?

Comment: I know it's running the right script because i put a var_dump(get_defined_vars()); at the beginning and it dumped out